# What would be the complexity of p = B^E?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here is my solution to p = B^E

```
p,b,e:= 1,B,E
  WHILE e!=0 DO
  IF e is EVEN THEN
    b:= b^2
    e:= e/2
  ELSE
    p:= p*b
    e:= e-1
  FI
 OD.
```

Now, in my view the loop runs E times and complexity is log n. Am I correct?

Here is how I would explain the complexity:

Explanation: In the worst case the loop will run E times but for each even number encountered, e is halved by 2, eliminating a factor of elements from the calculation, hence the size of the calculation will not grow exponentially when the input size grows. Therefore, the complexity of the algorithm is O(log (E) ).

Example: 
let us set E = 10
Then we will have calculation steps as below:
1. b := b^2 and e = 10/2 = 5
2. p = p*(b^2) and e = 5-1 = 4
3. b = b^4 and e = 4/2 = 2
3. b = b^8 and e = 1
4. p = p*b^10 and e = 0

Let’s increase the E to 100. Then we will have:

1. b := b^2 and e = 100/2 = 50
2. b := b^4 and e = 25
3. p := p*b^4 and e = 24
4. b := b^8 and e = 12
5. b := b^16 and e = 6
6. b := b^32 and e = 3
7. p := p * b^36 and e = 2
8. b := b * b^32 and e = 1
9. b := p * b^34 and e = 0
   Hence we see that increasing the size of E from 10 to 100 which is ten times doesn’t increases the number of iterations only by 5. Hence the complexity is proved to be O(log E)

Comment: I suspect that this belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ . Also, I'm not sure what it's actually asking, because I don't know what "B^E" is. This could be my failure as someone who hasn't studied much complexity theory, or it could be that the problem has not been sufficiently explained.

Answer (score 1):

Complexity is `O(logE)`.

Note that there could not be two ELSE condition one after the other, so in the worst case, so at most after two iterations, `e` will be reduced by half, until it becomes 0.

This means you are going to need at most `2*log_2(E)` iterations, which is indeed in `O(logE)`

---

Note that this does not include the aritmetics of squaring `b` over and over, which might add another factor to the equation, since when you are done, `b` will be in `O((B^2)^logE) = O(B^(2logE))`, which might not be `O(1)` to compute, depending on the architecture and actual sizes of `B,E`.

Comment: What does log E mean in general terms. If the the complexity is logE what does that mean to a general person who doesn't understand log?

Comment: @Randall I don't understand the question, `E` is an input to the described algorithm, you assign `e=E` in the first line of your pseudo code.

Comment: Yes, because the loop needs to run till E. E is the maximum value

Comment: @Randall And, as I explained, number of iterations required is `O(log(E))`, you don't need to run `E` iterations, only `log(E)`.

Comment: So, can I say that the maximum number of iterations in worst case is E but since the value is halved every time an even number is encountered, the complexity is O(Log E) because the as the input grows, iterations do not increase exponentially?

Comment: @Randall No, the worst case number of iterations is `2*log_2(E)`, not E.

Comment: Hi,I edited the question to explain how the complexity becomes O(log E). Does it look fine?

Comment: @Randall your solution is showing intuition, and not explaining why it also happens for larger numbers (As a TA I would give very few credit points for such answer)

Comment: So How can I prove it?

Comment: @Randall Following the lines I explained in my answer, please read it.